# Passing tab delimiter into variable C# Split function causing extra escape character

Tags: c#

My variable is getting changed to "\\t" instead of the "\t" when it gets passed into the Split function. Here is the relevant piece of code.

```
string FileDelimiter = Dts.Variables["User::vFileDelimiter"].Value.ToString();

public DataTable GetDataTableFromFile(string filePath, string connName, string fileDelimiter, string stageTable)
        {
            DataTable fileData = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                using (TextReader fileReader = File.OpenText(filePath))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = fileReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        string[] items = line.Trim().Split(fileDelimiter.ToCharArray());
```

Local variable output: Name=fileDelimiter, Value="\\t"

The FileDelimiter variable is populated with \t right out the gate. I have not used String.Split before. The issue caused an exception {"The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination."} System.InvalidOperationException. I am trying to parse through a tab delimited text file and grab the columns to load into a table.

Comment: I think that when you call `fileDelimiter.ToCharArray()` it is taking your string and splitting each into its own character. Perhaps trying to create your `FileDelimiter` like so would help: `char FileDelimiter = '\t';`.

Comment: `fileDelimiter.ToCharArray()` Should be fine actually. Perhaps it is just how you are storing and retrieving your value. This could use some debugging details and clarity.

Comment: I am storing the delimiter value in a SQL table. The value is \t. Then I query the table and assign the variable the value, which is in turn passed to the declared variable in the C# code.

Comment: Just cast your input to char: `(char)Dts.Variables["..."].Value` or using `if (char.TryParse(Dts.Variables["..."].Value, out var delimiter)) { }`

Comment: I did try casting it, but then I get a whole other set of issues saying cannot convert string to char in the Split function.

Comment: I believe [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-7.0) also supports using a string as a delimiter. Have you tried using the string value instead of the character?

Comment: Can you tell us the value of `FileDelimiter` before the `while` loop is entered?

Comment: What's the issue you are facing because of `\\t`?

Comment: The FileDelimiter variable is populated with \\t right out the gate. I have not used String.Split before. The issue caused an exception {"The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination."} System.InvalidOperationException. I am trying to parse through a tab delimited text file and grab the columns to load into a table.

Comment: Please add your last comment to the body of the question as it is relevant information. It seems like however you are storing it or loading it is changing your value. Unfortunately that is not visible to us, so we are unable to help.

Comment: Which line in the code throws the exception? Are you sure that the file has tab delimited data? Did you debug your code and check if you are getting correct values in `items`?  How they are different from the expected values?

Comment: Yes the item list looks screwed up. The line looks like this "MedicareContractID\tMedicarePlanID\tMedicareSegmentID\tNPI\tProviderAddressLine1\tProviderAddressLine2\tProviderCity\tProviderState\tProviderZip\tProviderSpecialty\tPCPID\tIsAcceptingNewPatients" and items looks like this.

Comment: [0] "MedicareCon" string
  [1] "rac" string
  [2] "ID\tMedicarePlanID\tMedicareSegmen" string
  [3] "ID\tNPI\tProviderAddressLine1\tProviderAddressLine2\tProviderCi" string
  [4] "y\tProviderS" string
  [5] "a" string
  [6] "e\tProviderZip\tProviderSpecial" string
  [7] "y\tPCPID\tIsAccep" string
  [8] "ingNewPa" string
  [9] "ien" string
  [10] "s" string

Comment: The exception in thrown when it tries to map the columns with the table columns apparently due to the fact the column names arent getting split correctly.

Comment: If `FileDelimeter.Length == 2`, then your problem is how you store the delimeter in the database.  Tab is just one character and therefore its length must be 1.  You are probably thinking that there is a 1:1 correlation between how your DB interprets strings to how C# does it.

Comment: Sounds like you actually have the string `\t` stored in the database rather than a single tab character. Note that an sql constant like `select '\t'` will actually return `"\\t"`.

Comment: I do have the value in the database as \t. How would I put a single tab character instead?

Comment: Never mind I figured it out. @Jeremy, thanks so much for pointing this out. It only took me all day to make it work lol!